# Set current array using a string

Tags: php

If *$point* is **333** (for example) I want *current($ids)* to be **444**:

```
$ids = array(111, 222, 333, 444);
$point = 333;
```

If *$point* is **444**, *current($ids)* to be **111** and so on.

---

I have this code, but I was looking for something more simple:

```
$ids = array(111, 222, 333, 444, 555);
$point = array_search(555, $ids);

while(key($ids) != $point) {
    next($ids);
}

$point = next($ids);

if($point == NULL) {
    $point = reset($ids);
}

echo $point;
```

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve. There is standard function `current()` - you want it to return first element of an array if you've reached end of array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(key($ids) != $point) {
    next($ids);
}

$toEcho = next($ids);
if (!$toEcho) {
    $toEcho = reset($ids);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reset the array when next is not found

```
while(key($ids) != $point) {
    if (next($ids) === false) reset($ids);
}
```

Comment: +1. Full featured since still is infinite loop proned. -- edited: and now question changed.